# Analyzing a counting triangles streaming algorithm which uses $\ell_0$ sampling

Tags: graphs, algorithm-analysis, combinatorics, randomized-algorithms, streaming-algorithm

I'm trying to analyze the following streaming algorithm for counting triangles (see below). It supposedly works also for dynamic graphs (i.e. "turnstile model", where edge deletions are allowed).

1. What am I missing? According to my (buggy) analysis of the reported estimator's variance, the variance equal to 0 (see below).
2. How should I analyze the use in an $\ell_0$-sampler? (Currently, my analysis ignore it)

Algorithm:

1. Init: Define $k := O(\frac {n^3} {\epsilon^2 t})$. Pick $k$ random subsets $S_1, \ldots, S_k \subset V$ each of size 3 (with repetitions).
2. Update: For each random subset of size 3, denoted $S_i$, maintain a counter $x_{S_i}$, which represent the number of internal edges in $S_i$, i.e. a number in $\{0, 1, 2, 3\}$.
3. Output: Use an $\ell_o$-sampler over the vector $x = (x_{S_1}, \ldots, x_{S_k})$ to pick an index $j \in [k]$ (i.e. $j$ is chosen uniformly at random from $\{i \in [k] : x_{S_i} > 0\}$). Compute $z := \mathbb{1}[x_{S_j} = 3], N = \|x\|_0$. Report $\tilde{T} = N \cdot z$.

Analysis, where $T$ is the number of triangles:
$$
\begin{split}
E[\tilde T] &= E[N \cdot z] \\
&= N \cdot E[z] \\
&= \|x\|_0 \cdot E \left[ \mathbb{1} \left[ x_{S_j} = 3 \right] \right] \\
&= \|x\|_0 \cdot \Pr \left[ x_{S_j} = 3 \right] \\
&= \|x\|_0 \cdot \frac T {\|x\|_0} \\
&= T
\end{split}
$$

Which seems to be ok. But for the variance:
$$
\begin{split}
Var[\tilde T] &= Var[N \cdot z] \\
&= N^2 \cdot Var[z] \\
\end{split}
$$
Then
$$
\begin{split}
Var[z] &= Var \left[ \mathbb{1} \left[ x_{S_j} = 3 \right] \right] \\
&= E \left[ \left( \mathbb{1} \left[ x_{S_j} = 3 \right] \right)^2 \right] - \left( E \left[ \mathbb{1} \left[ x_{S_j} = 3 \right] \right]  \right)^2 \\
&= E \left[ \mathbb{1} \left[ x_{S_j} = 3 \right], \mathbb{1} \left[ x_{S_i} = 3 \right] \right] - \left( \frac {T} {\|x\|_0} \right)^2 \\
&= \Pr \left[x_{S_j} = 3 , x_{S_i} = 3 \right] - \left( \frac {T} {\|x\|_0} \right)^2 \\
&= \left( \Pr \left[x_{S_j} = 3 \right] \right)^2 - \left( \frac {T} {\|x\|_0} \right)^2 \\
&= \left( \frac {T} {\|x\|_0} \right)^2 - \left( \frac {T} {\|x\|_0} \right)^2 \\
&= 0
\end{split}
$$

Comment: You're using $\Pr[A,A] = \Pr[A]^2$. In fact, $\Pr[A,A] = \Pr[A]$.

Comment: Thank you for pointing it out. Regarding my 2nd question on the $\ell_0$-sampler: Is it ok to ignore the fact that the index $j$ (from line 3) is the result of the sampler (as I ignore it in the analysis above)?

Comment: You should definitely not ignore it. It should be part of the analysis.

Comment: I suggest reviewing class material.

Comment: Thank you. In class, we talked about the theorem of Jowhari, Saglam, and Tardos from 2011, which states that "$\exists$ a streaming algorithm for $\ell_0$ sampling that reports: (1) FAIL with probability $\le \delta$; xor (2) arbitrary answer with probability $\le \frac 1 {n^2}$; xor (3) a uniform sample from $supp(x)$ with the remaining probability. The algorithm has space complexity of $O(\log^2 (n) \log (\frac 1 \delta))$ bits.".
Now when I have the index $j$ which is the result of the $\ell_0$ sampler, I'm not sure how to take it into account. Intuitively I know I should, but how?

Comment: For example, how should we interpret $\Pr \left[ \mathbb{1} \left[ x_{S_j} = 3 \right] \right]$? By assuming that $j$ was chosen uniformly at random, and ignoring the possibilities that the $\ell_0$ sampler was wrong (i.e. reported (1) FAIL, or (2) arbitrary answer), we get that the above equal to $\frac T {\|x\|_0}$.

Comment: This is meaningless, since $\mathbb{1}[x_{S_j}=3]$ is not an event. You mean $\Pr[x_{S_j}=3] = \mathbb{E}[\mathbb{1}[x_{S_j}=3]]$.

Comment: Right, thank you. I also fixed the notation in the original question. So my question is, for example, how should we interpret $\Pr[_{_}=3]$ (where $j$ is the result of a $\ell_0$ sampler)? Best regards

Comment: It's the probability that if you run the algorithm, then $x_{S_j} = 3$.

Comment: Yes. Thank you for your fast reply. According to Jowhari, Saglam, and Tardos (2011), there are three possible results of the sampler. It would be easier to analyze $\Pr \left[ x_{S_j} = 3 \right]$ if the sampler had only the following two results: (1) report FAIL, xor (3) successfully reporting an uniform sample from $supp(x)$. But according to their theory, there is an additional possible result which is described above as: (2) reporting an arbitrary answer. I'm not sure how to take the existence of result (2) into account when interpreting $\Pr \left[ x_{S_j} = 3 \right]$.

Comment: If (2) happens, then all you can say about this probability is that it's between 0 and 1. But since (2) happens with small probability, it doesn't affect the final answer by much.